# Поправка в движке

Tags: php

У меня есть движок:

```
<?php
include ('http://pokelight.pz9.ru/core.php');
$page = $_GET['page'];
switch ($page) {
 default :
 case '':
      include ('http://pokelight.pz9.ru/style/main.php');
 break;
 case 'register':
      include ('http://pokelight.pz9.ru/style/register.php');   
 break;

 }
 ?>
```

на Локальном сервере он работает , а как залил его, ток перестал работать =) Подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
include ('/core.php');
$page = (isset($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page']:'default';
switch ($page) {
   case ('register'):
        include ('/style/register.php');   
        break;
   default :
        include ('/style/main.php');
        break;
}
?>
```

Правда мне не понятно что делают главная страница и страница регистрации в папке **style**. Вы бы пути проверили...

Answer (score 0):

видимо на хостинге в php.ini запрещен инклюд ссылок

```
allow_url_include = Off
allow_url_fopen = Off
```

а нужно что бы было On

если все файлы лежат на этом же сервере, то необходимо сделать так как написал **DemoS**